# JSZip, Jquery, Fetch, Promises, handle multiple promises in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api, jszip

I have multiple promise object (of different types) that need to be executed in sequence.

```
var zip = new JSZip(), config = {...}
localforage.iterate(function(...) {
    // do stuff in loop
}).then(function(result) {
   $.getScript("/my/precompiled/template.js")
   .then(function(obj) {
      // build files based on scope imported inside template.js
      zip.file("file.js", Handlebars.templates["js"](config));
      zip.file("file.css", Handlebars.templates["css"](config));
      zip.file("file.html", Handlebars.templates["html"](config));
   })
   .then(function(obj) {
      // get a file based on a config variable previously set somewhere
      fetch("/" + config.somevalue + "/prepackaged.zip")
      .then(function(response) {
          return response.arrayBuffer();
      })
      .then(function(ab) {
         // add a file based on a template named after that config variable
         zip.file("somefile.txt", Handlebars.templates[config.somevalue](config));
         zip.loadAsync(ab)
         .then(function(inst) {
             zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
             .then(function(content) {
                // ... download as zip
             });
         });
      })
```

So, iterate a loop and THEN load a script and evaluate it so that it can be used by Handlebars in the next step, THEN add some files, THEN fetch a zip file based on a property that was set, THEN load the bytes of that fetch into the zip file, THEN add some more files, THEN generate the zip file, THEN download it to the user ..

So localforage returns a promise. I then need to use jQuery's getScript to finish. After that, I need to use Fetch which returns a promise, and then JSZip which returns a promise ... they aren't all the same type of object nor the same type of promise.

What is the best way to sequentially work through a series of different objects that each return a promise?

Comment: `What is the best way to sequentially work through a series of different objects that each return a promise?` chain them, using `.then`

Comment: @JaromandaX even if some are jquery promises that must exist before a fetch promise?

Comment: As long as they conform to Promise/A+ spec, then you should be fine - note: early jQuery promises were a little broken

Comment: the code `.then(function(obj) {` .... `.then(function(obj) {` looks suspicious, as the second .then in that sequence will have `undefined` as obj, because the sequence inside that block has no return ... does `zip.file` run asynchronously? if so, that is also a problem in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX zip.file is asynchronous, as is fetch, I see what you're saying now about the thens - I just have to return the correct objects

Comment: `zip.file is asynchronous` can you run them in parallel like you are? or do they need to be in series too?

Comment: iterate must run first, the jquery template load must be finished before the zip steps can take place (which can happen at the same time), and finally once all those zip steps are done, the package can be generated then downloaded.

Comment: Not sure to be honest, but https://jsfiddle.net/rkyajs4n/1/ not only should do what you describe, but also flattens your Promise chain considerably **edit:** oops had a missing `()` in the original

Comment: @JaromandaX Cheers, I'd just come up with something similar myself (the `promise.all` is neat trick)

Comment: if you want to see how it looks in ES2015+ https://jsfiddle.net/rkyajs4n/3/